# Как узнать, касаются ли два объекта в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Как реализовать объекты через которые не может проходить игрок (стенки) в pygame

Comment: думаю вам будет полезно посмотреть https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjRuaCofWO0O8qv2or33DGHpQ6kN_CATM если не путаю, то 4е видео это ваш вопрос

Comment: спасибо за информацию

Comment: Погуглил пример для pygame: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739362/5909792 Придется поразбираться, но код отличный и будет полезным

Answer (score 0):

я обычно это делал путем задания геометрических параметров. Я прописывал контуры уравнениями аналитчисекой геометрии. То есть, если у нас в цикле при нажатии кнопки меняется координата движущейся фигурки, то менятся она (координата x,y) может только в определенных диапазонах. Вот в каких? Дальше вы вспоминаете аналитическую геометрию. Задаете все контуры уравнениями (прямых, кривых, эллипсов) и условиями  If, в которых вы прописываете, что будет если фигурка пересечет прописанную уравнениями линию. Я не спорю, возможно это не самый легкий метод, но по моему мнению наиболее правильный. 
вот пример кода

```
        while b:  # заводим бесконечный цикл
            for i in pygame.event.get():
                # pygame.font.init()
                if i.type == pygame.QUIT:  # нажимаем кнопку закрытия экрана
                    pygame.time.delay(20)
                if i.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # нажимаем что-нибудь на мыши
                    if i.button == 1:  # клик ЛКМ
                        x = i.pos[0] #захватываем координаты
                        y = i.pos[1]
                        if x > 844 and x < 1073 and y > 607 and y < 703:
                            self.GUI('1.jpg',1276,724)
                        if x > 46 and x < 421 and y > 111 and y < 261:  
                            self.GUI('2.jpg', 1276, 724)
                        if x > 46 and x < 422 and y > 261 and y < 424:  
                            self.GUI('3.jpg', 1276, 724)
                        if x > 47 and x < 423 and y > 426 and y < 582:          self.GUI('4.jpg', 1276, 724)
                        if x > 125 and x < 354 and y > 611 and y < 707:
                            pygame.quit()
                            exit()
```

То есть тут, при клике мышей по различным областям инициализируются разные действия. А вот области получаются из уравнений.

Comment: Ответ подробный, но не хватает кода :)

Comment: Кода какого? Пришлите конкретную задачу)1. Как вы двигаете фигуру? 2. Что из себя преставляют препятствия?

Comment: Задача не у меня, а у автора вопроса и у него вопрос коллизии объектов